# Create store property is disabled with no clear reason

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, command, shadcnui

I'm following a tutorial on youtube about making a dashboard cms project with Next Js, and I worked with shadcn-ui components ( command component ), but the teacher in the video te create store property worked with him, but not for me, knowing that we have the same code. [image]

[image]